# How to solve the dining philosophers problem with only mutexes?

Tags: c, multithreading, dining-philosopher

I wrote this program to solve the [dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) using Dijkstra's algorithm, notice that I'm using an array of booleans (`data->locked`) instead of an array of binary semaphores.

I'm not sure if this solution is valid (hence the SO question).

Will access to the `data->locked` array in both `test` and `take_forks` functions cause data races? if so is it even possible to solve this problem using Dijkstra's algorithm with only mutexes?

I'm only allowed to use mutexes, no semaphores, no condition variables (it's an assignment).

Example of usage:

```sh
./a.out 4 1000 1000
```

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NOT_HUNGRY  1
#define HUNGRY      2
#define EATING      3
#define RIGHT   ((i + 1) % data->n)
#define LEFT    ((i + data->n - 1) % data->n)

typedef struct s_data
{
    int             n;
    int             t_sleep;
    int             t_eat;
    int             *state;
    bool            *locked;
    pthread_mutex_t *state_mutex;
}   t_data;

typedef struct s_arg
{
    t_data  *data;
    int     i;
}   t_arg;

int ft_min(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return (a);
    return (b);
}

int ft_max(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return (a);
    return (b);
}

// if the LEFT and RIGHT threads are not eating
// and thread number i is hungry, change its state to EATING
// and signal to the while loop in `take_forks` to stop blocking.
// if a thread has a state of HUNGRY then it's guaranteed
// to be out of the critical section of `take_forks`.
void    test(int i, t_data *data)
{
    if (
        data->state[i] == HUNGRY
        && data->state[LEFT] != EATING
        && data->state[RIGHT] != EATING
    )
    {
        data->state[i] = EATING;
        data->locked[i] = false;
    }
}

// set the state of the thread number i to HUNGRY
// and block until the LEFT and RIGHT threads are not EATING
// in which case they will call `test` from `put_forks`
// which will result in breaking the while loop
void    take_forks(int i, t_data *data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(data->state_mutex);
    data->locked[i] = true;
    data->state[i] = HUNGRY;
    test(i, data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(data->state_mutex);
    while (data->locked[i]);
}

// set the state of the thread number i to NOT_HUNGRY
// then signal to the LEFT and RIGHT threads
// so they can start eating when their neighbors are not eating
void    put_forks(int i, t_data *data)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(data->state_mutex);
    data->state[i] = NOT_HUNGRY;
    test(LEFT, data);
    test(RIGHT, data);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(data->state_mutex);
}

void    *philosopher(void *_arg)
{
    t_arg   *arg = _arg;

    while (true)
    {
        printf("%d is thinking\n", arg->i);
        take_forks(arg->i, arg->data);
        printf("%d is eating\n", arg->i);
        usleep(arg->data->t_eat * 1000);
        put_forks(arg->i, arg->data);
        printf("%d is sleeping\n", arg->i);
        usleep(arg->data->t_sleep * 1000);
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void    data_init(t_data *data, pthread_mutex_t *state_mutex, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;

    data->n = atoi(argv[1]);
    data->t_eat = atoi(argv[2]);
    data->t_sleep = atoi(argv[3]);
    pthread_mutex_init(state_mutex, NULL);
    data->state_mutex = state_mutex;
    data->state = malloc(data->n * sizeof(int));
    data->locked = malloc(data->n * sizeof(bool));
    while (i < data->n)
    {
        data->state[i] = NOT_HUNGRY;
        data->locked[i] = true;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_mutex_t state_mutex;
    t_data          data;
    t_arg           *args;
    pthread_t       *threads;
    int             i;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fputs("Error\nInvalid argument count\n", stderr);
        return (1);
    }
    data_init(&data, &state_mutex, argv);
    args = malloc(data.n * sizeof(t_arg));
    i = 0;
    while (i < data.n)
    {
        args[i].data = &data;
        args[i].i = i;
        i++;
    }
    threads = malloc(data.n * sizeof(pthread_t));
    i = 0;
    while (i < data.n)
    {
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, philosopher, args + i);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < data.n)
        pthread_join(threads[i++], NULL);
}
```

Comment: I think you locks are good and conservative (I could be wrong tho), but I really dont like  `while (data->locked[i]);` that cries out for a conditon varaible

Comment: yes, that's true. but I'm only allowed to use mutexes, no semaphores, no condition variables (it's an assignment).

Comment: Spinning on `locked` is by definition a data race.  There is no guarantee that something hasn't just acquired a mutex and is about to modify this value.  If you're using this loop for any kind of synchronization, I'd say all bets are off unless there's a very specific kind of design behind this that makes it reasonable.  I can't see any, and there's no comments in your code that might explain the logic and sequencing.  _Caveat:_ I haven't done a full analysis of your program, and am not familiar with the problem being solved.

Comment: at least maybe sleep in that loop - please :-)

Comment: @paddy the spin is done after locks are released

Comment: Yes, that's the bit I find uneasy.  From purely local perspective, there is no guarantee that after `while (data->locked[i]);` completes, that `data->locked[i]` won't be true again. Maybe it's a logical guarantee of the algorithm, but it sure looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @paddy like you said, it's a logical guarantee of the algorithm, `data->locked[i]` can only be set to true by the thread number `i`, while it can be set to false by the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` thread (LEFT and RIGHT are macros to simplify calculating thread indexes).

Comment: I added some comments to the important functions to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `pthread_mutex_trylock()` ?   Ref: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_trylock.3p.html

Comment: @Kingsley, unfortunately, no, these are the mutex related functions I'm allowed to use: `pthread_mutex_init` `pthread_mutex_destroy` `pthread_mutex_lock` `pthread_mutex_unlock`

Comment: As paddy said, `while (data->locked[i]);` is a data race; you don't hold the lock while reading it, and so another thread could take the lock and write while you are reading. In fact, you rely on that happening. But this is undefined behavior.  Immediate practical consequences are that the compiler can delete the test (since in the absence of a data race, `data->locked[i]` could not change between iterations), or delete the loop altogether (since it's now an infinite loop, and nontrivial infinite loops are UB).

Comment: So you have to hold the mutex while testing the flag.  If it's false, you should then *hold* the mutex until you set it true and do your other work; otherwise there is a race where another thread could get it first.  If it's true, then drop the mutex, wait a little while, take it again, and retry.

Comment: @NateEldredge inside the while loop, I'll have to calculate the elapsed time since the last meal of the thread or threads that are waiting for their respective Boolean to become false, and if it's past a certain limit I have to stop the simulation, so do I have to make the thread sleep before holding the mutex again ? what I mean here is that instead of sleeping, maybe I can instead do a little bit of work like calculating the elapsed time.

Comment: @NateEldredge that's the solution I was looking for, can you please make your comments into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spin loop `while (data->locked[i]);` is a data race; you don't hold the lock while reading it `data->locked[i]`, and so another thread could take the lock and write to that same variable while you are reading it. In fact, you rely on that happening. But this is undefined behavior.

Immediate practical consequences are that the compiler can delete the test (since in the absence of a data race, `data->locked[i]` could not change between iterations), or delete the loop altogether (since it's now an infinite loop, and nontrivial infinite loops are UB).  Of course other undesired outcomes are also possible.

So you have to hold the mutex while testing the flag. If it's false, you should then hold the mutex until you set it true and do your other work; otherwise there is a race where another thread could get it first. If it's true, then drop the mutex, wait a little while, take it again, and retry.

(How long is a "little while", and what work you choose to do in between, are probably things you should test.  Depending on what kind of fairness algorithms your pthread implementation uses, you might run into situations where `take_forks` succeeds in retaking the lock even if `put_forks` is also waiting to lock it.)

Of course, in a "real" program, you wouldn't do it this way in the first place; you'd use a condition variable.